# How to use flex tilelist data effects combined with a ListCollectionView dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, effects, tilelist

I am using a TileList control with an effect sequence linked to the itemsChangeEffect property.

```
<mx:TileList
    itemsChangeEffect="{dataChangeEffectSequence}"
    ...>
</mx:TileList >


<mx:Sequence id="dataChangeEffectSequence">
   <mx:Blur 
      blurYTo="12" blurXTo="12" 
      duration="250" 
      perElementOffset="150"
      filter="removeItem"/> 
   <mx:Move 
      duration="1500"
      easingFunction="{Elastic.easeOut}" 
      perElementOffset="20"/>
   ...
</mx:Sequence>
```

The resulting effect is pretty neat. For example, when removing an item from the data provider, it will blur out and the other items will move to fill the empty space.

However, my data provider is a ListCollectionView that I use to filter items. When I set a filter criteria, it will hide a couple of items from the TileList but there is no animation like when I remove an item. Is there a way to animate the TileList when an item is filtered ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a list can you just do the following?

```
<mx:List removedEffect="{dataChangeEffectSequence}"/>
```

Or move the effect definitions from the custom component to the same container which contains the Repeater statement and add the effect triggers to the repeated component within the Repeater statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, the removeEffect is applied when you remove the list itself and not an individual element contained in the list.